# How to find list of points on line on canvas android

Tags: android, canvas, path

I drawn line on canvas passing two points on drawlinw() method.
Now i want to get list of all points of line i drawn.
My purpose to do this is - I want to draw circles on line at certain interval.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use analytical equation for you line, received from coordinates of this two points. In this case you will know any Y for any X on your line ([look at this article](http://www.calcfun.com/calculate-41-equation-of-a-line-given-that-you-know-two-points-it-passes-through.html)).

Comment: Can you please guide me what is this equation in maths ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can get this information from the Canvas: you probably need to compute those points manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't with Android API, but you certainly can compute your interval yourself, can't you ?